# Как можно определить вводимые с клавиатуры символы? windows, winapi

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, input, клавиатура

Я сделал текстовый редактор. Изучать richedit control мне было лень по этому создал своё текстовое поле.
Нужно определять вводимые символы в соответствии с выбранной раскладкой клавиатуры.
Какая раскладка активна можно узнать легко. Но как получать нужный символ?
Единственное пока решение это вручную указать символы, как я и сделал.
[image: 1]

А нужно автоматически получать символы безовсяких массивов

Comment: 'Но как получать нужный символ?' Не совсем ясно, что именно вы имеете ввиду под этим вопросом. Вообще, первое что приходит на ум при работе с символами - использовать ASCII-коды.

Comment: "Нужно определять вводимые символы в соответствии с выбранной раскладкой клавиатуры." - вроде ясно написал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взято из движка irrlicht

```
HKL KEYBOARD_INPUT_HKL=0;
unsigned int KEYBOARD_INPUT_CODEPAGE = 1252;
static unsigned int LocaleIdToCodepage(unsigned int lcid)
{
    switch ( lcid )
    {
        case 1098:  // Telugu
        case 1095:  // Gujarati
        case 1094:  // Punjabi
        case 1103:  // Sanskrit
        case 1111:  // Konkani
        case 1114:  // Syriac
        case 1099:  // Kannada
        case 1102:  // Marathi
        case 1125:  // Divehi
        case 1067:  // Armenian
        case 1081:  // Hindi
        case 1079:  // Georgian
        case 1097:  // Tamil
            return 0;
        case 1054:  // Thai
            return 874;
        case 1041:  // Japanese
            return 932;
        case 2052:  // Chinese (PRC)
        case 4100:  // Chinese (Singapore)
            return 936;
        case 1042:  // Korean
            return 949;
        case 5124:  // Chinese (Macau S.A.R.)
        case 3076:  // Chinese (Hong Kong S.A.R.)
        case 1028:  // Chinese (Taiwan)
            return 950;
        case 1048:  // Romanian
        case 1060:  // Slovenian
        case 1038:  // Hungarian
        case 1051:  // Slovak
        case 1045:  // Polish
        case 1052:  // Albanian
        case 2074:  // Serbian (Latin)
        case 1050:  // Croatian
        case 1029:  // Czech
            return 1250;
        case 1104:  // Mongolian (Cyrillic)
        case 1071:  // FYRO Macedonian
        case 2115:  // Uzbek (Cyrillic)
        case 1058:  // Ukrainian
        case 2092:  // Azeri (Cyrillic)
        case 1092:  // Tatar
        case 1087:  // Kazakh
        case 1059:  // Belarusian
        case 1088:  // Kyrgyz (Cyrillic)
        case 1026:  // Bulgarian
        case 3098:  // Serbian (Cyrillic)
        case 1049:  // Russian
            return 1251;
        case 8201:  // English (Jamaica)
        case 3084:  // French (Canada)
        case 1036:  // French (France)
        case 5132:  // French (Luxembourg)
        case 5129:  // English (New Zealand)
        case 6153:  // English (Ireland)
        case 1043:  // Dutch (Netherlands)
        case 9225:  // English (Caribbean)
        case 4108:  // French (Switzerland)
        case 4105:  // English (Canada)
        case 1110:  // Galician
        case 10249:  // English (Belize)
        case 3079:  // German (Austria)
        case 6156:  // French (Monaco)
        case 12297:  // English (Zimbabwe)
        case 1069:  // Basque
        case 2067:  // Dutch (Belgium)
        case 2060:  // French (Belgium)
        case 1035:  // Finnish
        case 1080:  // Faroese
        case 1031:  // German (Germany)
        case 3081:  // English (Australia)
        case 1033:  // English (United States)
        case 2057:  // English (United Kingdom)
        case 1027:  // Catalan
        case 11273:  // English (Trinidad)
        case 7177:  // English (South Africa)
        case 1030:  // Danish
        case 13321:  // English (Philippines)
        case 15370:  // Spanish (Paraguay)
        case 9226:  // Spanish (Colombia)
        case 5130:  // Spanish (Costa Rica)
        case 7178:  // Spanish (Dominican Republic)
        case 12298:  // Spanish (Ecuador)
        case 17418:  // Spanish (El Salvador)
        case 4106:  // Spanish (Guatemala)
        case 18442:  // Spanish (Honduras)
        case 3082:  // Spanish (International Sort)
        case 13322:  // Spanish (Chile)
        case 19466:  // Spanish (Nicaragua)
        case 2058:  // Spanish (Mexico)
        case 10250:  // Spanish (Peru)
        case 20490:  // Spanish (Puerto Rico)
        case 1034:  // Spanish (Traditional Sort)
        case 14346:  // Spanish (Uruguay)
        case 8202:  // Spanish (Venezuela)
        case 1089:  // Swahili
        case 1053:  // Swedish
        case 2077:  // Swedish (Finland)
        case 5127:  // German (Liechtenstein)
        case 1078:  // Afrikaans
        case 6154:  // Spanish (Panama)
        case 4103:  // German (Luxembourg)
        case 16394:  // Spanish (Bolivia)
        case 2055:  // German (Switzerland)
        case 1039:  // Icelandic
        case 1057:  // Indonesian
        case 1040:  // Italian (Italy)
        case 2064:  // Italian (Switzerland)
        case 2068:  // Norwegian (Nynorsk)
        case 11274:  // Spanish (Argentina)
        case 1046:  // Portuguese (Brazil)
        case 1044:  // Norwegian (Bokmal)
        case 1086:  // Malay (Malaysia)
        case 2110:  // Malay (Brunei Darussalam)
        case 2070:  // Portuguese (Portugal)
            return 1252;
        case 1032:  // Greek
            return 1253;
        case 1091:  // Uzbek (Latin)
        case 1068:  // Azeri (Latin)
        case 1055:  // Turkish
            return 1254;
        case 1037:  // Hebrew
            return 1255;
        case 5121:  // Arabic (Algeria)
        case 15361:  // Arabic (Bahrain)
        case 9217:  // Arabic (Yemen)
        case 3073:  // Arabic (Egypt)
        case 2049:  // Arabic (Iraq)
        case 11265:  // Arabic (Jordan)
        case 13313:  // Arabic (Kuwait)
        case 12289:  // Arabic (Lebanon)
        case 4097:  // Arabic (Libya)
        case 6145:  // Arabic (Morocco)
        case 8193:  // Arabic (Oman)
        case 16385:  // Arabic (Qatar)
        case 1025:  // Arabic (Saudi Arabia)
        case 10241:  // Arabic (Syria)
        case 14337:  // Arabic (U.A.E.)
        case 1065:  // Farsi
        case 1056:  // Urdu
        case 7169:  // Arabic (Tunisia)
            return 1256;
        case 1061:  // Estonian
        case 1062:  // Latvian
        case 1063:  // Lithuanian
            return 1257;
        case 1066:  // Vietnamese
            return 1258;
    }
    return 65001;   // utf-8
}
```

...

```
case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
case WM_SYSKEYUP:
case WM_KEYDOWN:
case WM_KEYUP:
    {
        BYTE allKeys[256];
        ...
        GetKeyboardState(allKeys);
        WORD keyChars[2];
        UINT scanCode = HIWORD(lParam);
        int conversionResult = ToAsciiEx(wParam,scanCode,allKeys,keyChars,0,KEYBOARD_INPUT_HKL);
        if( conversionResult == 1 )
        {
            WORD unicodeChar;
            MultiByteToWideChar(
                    KEYBOARD_INPUT_CODEPAGE,
                    MB_PRECOMPOSED, // default
                    (LPCSTR)keyChars,
                    sizeof(keyChars),
                    (WCHAR*)&unicodeChar,
                    1 );                
        wprintf(L"Char [%c]\n",unicodeChar);
        }
    }break;
case WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE:
    // get the new codepage used for keyboard input
    KEYBOARD_INPUT_HKL = GetKeyboardLayout(0);
    KEYBOARD_INPUT_CODEPAGE = LocaleIdToCodepage( LOWORD(KEYBOARD_INPUT_HKL)
);
return 0;
```